# when trying to navigate to some element in the same route the href loads in the URL

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

so i'm trying to navigate to an element in the same page in an angular route
but it's not working it directs me to a different route

```
<h2>Food</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#pizzas">Pizzas</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="category1 mt-3">
  <h3 id="pizzas">Pizzas</h3>
```

so how to it

Comment: within an angular route ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use NavigationExtras [official docs here](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Or like so:
`<li class="list-group-item"><a [routerLink]="['/your-route']" fragment="pizzas">Pizzas</a></li>`